# Convert Object Array to an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a returned object list: data.d[15]

and one sample of it:

```
data.d[3] = {
CityId: 2,
CityName: "Ankara"}
```

I want to convert it to one object as

```
cities{
1: "Istanbul",
2: "Ankara",
3: "New York"
}
```

And it should be generic, so I dont know the "CityId" and "CityName" field names.
what is the best method for it?

thank you all... i have send fieldnames by field object -no dependencies important for this code-, it has been resolved.

```
            var url = this.options.url + "/" + field.values,
                id = field.fieldId,
                title = field.fieldTitle;

            this.getJSON(url, {}, function (rData) {
                var obj = {};

                for (i = 0; i < rData.d.length; i++)
                    obj[rData.d[i][id]] = rData.d[i][title];

                $("#" + parentId).html(self.getHtmlOfFormData(type, obj));
            });
```

Comment: if you don't know `CityName`, then how are we supposed to know what to project?

Comment: I can't really see a correlation between those two pieces of data and how it can be generic. Perhaps you need to be more specific.

Comment: I just want to get first value as ID and second value as Val without FieldName dependency.

Comment: @kirlisakal There is no "first" or "second" value in an object. The order of the keys depends on the implementation of the browser.

Comment: @kirlisakal Unfortunately, you can't be sure about the order of the properties when you iterate on them. You need to check their type.

Comment: thank you all...
I decide to get fieldnames into function, so I have no dependency to fieldnames too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to detect which property contains the name of the city. Maybe something like this can work?

```
var idprop, nameprop;
for (var prop in data.d[0]) {
    if (typeof data.d[0][prop] === "string") nameprop = prop;
    if (typeof data.d[0][prop] === "number") idprop = prop;
}

var cities = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
   cities[data.d[i][idprop]] = data.d[i][nameprop];
```

Keep in mind that this works if:

1. `data.d` isn't an empty array;
2. there's just one string property that contains the city name;
3. there's just one numeric property that contains the city id.

Comment: i + 1 should be data.d[i].CityId

Comment: @Chango Maybe, but we need confirmation from kirlisakal

Comment: hey thank you much...
I have solved the problem as I get the fieldnames by variant, cuz id's type is not allways numeric.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question, you are trying to convert some ajax return that looks like this:

```
data.d = [
    {
        cityId: someNumber1,
        cityName: someName1
    },
    {
        cityId: someNumber2,
        cityName: someName2
    }
];
```

into an object that looks like this:

```
cities = {
    someNumber1: someName1,
    someNumber2: someName2
};
```

a snippet like this would do the trick:

```
var cities = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    cities[data.d[i].cityId] = data.d[i].cityName;
}
```